# Excel VBA - Trato de crear archivos de texto según la hoja que requiera el usuario

Tags: excel, vba

Cree un formulario para que el usuario pueda seleccionar una Hoja existente en el Libro desde un Dropdown.
Una vez seleccionado, debería tocar un botón y enviar los valores para crear archivos de textos de cada fila, pero solo de la Hoja seleccionada anteriormente.
Logre hacerlo funcionar sobre una Hoja determinada, pero no logro que funcione dinámicamente enviándole el nombre de la Hoja como parámetro.

```
Sub SaveAsTextFile(catSelected As String, codeSelected As Integer)
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strReport As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    
    strPath = "E:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Products\"
    
    With Worksheets(catSelected)
    
        m = .Range("A2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For r = 2 To m
            strReport = Range("F2" & r).Value
            Open strPath & codeSelected & ".txt" For Output As #1
            Print #1, strReport
            Close #1
            codeSelected = codeSelected + 1
        Next r
        
    End With
        
End Sub
```

El nombre de la hoja se lo paso cuando hago click en un boton del formulario:

```
Private Sub generateProducts_Click()
    Dim cat As String
    Dim code As Integer
    
    cat = categoriesList.Value
    code = CInt(initialCode.Value)
    
    Call SaveAsTextFile(cat, code)
End Sub
```

Gracias!

Comment: Español, por favor. [edit] y traduce todo, incluyendo el título.

Comment: ¡Gracias por traducirla! Dos aclaraciones, por favor: 1) en dónde viajaría el nombre de la hoja existente? 2) Así como está no te saca los datos de la hoja que le indicas? Cómo te funciona "sobre una hoja determinada"?

Comment: Actualice el articulo con el código del botón.
Asi como esta, me da error 1004, cuando Depuro el codigo me señala "m = .Range("A2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: `m = .Range("A2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` está mal. Fíjate que tienes puesto `A2` y lo concatenas con `Rows.Count`, con lo que creas un número superior a las filas que admite Excel. Borra el 2. Deja solo `m = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`